# Get Top Rated Products and Order by rating

Tags: magento2.2, product-collection

I want to get Top Rated Products collection and sort it by ratings. I'm using the code but not working.

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                        'rating_option_vote_aggregated',
                        'e.entity_id = rating_option_vote_aggregated.entity_pk_value',
                        array('vote_count' => 'SUM(rating_option_vote_aggregated.vote_count)'))
                ->group('e.entity_id')
                ->order('vote_count ' . $this->getCurrentDirectionReverse());
```

> [2019-04-01 12:51:58] main.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vote_count ' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) AS `visibility`, SUM(rating_option_vote_aggregated.vote_count) AS `vote_count`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1)
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default` ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 1)
>    LEFT JOIN `rating_option_vote_aggregated` ON e.entity_id = rating_option_vote_aggregated.entity_pk_value
>    INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1') AND (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) = '4') AND (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` ORDER BY `vote_count` ASC
>    LIMIT 8 [] []